# Are there any browser-compatibility issues with recursion in a named IIFE?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, iife

I'm doing a recursive operation, and the most straightforward approach would be a named, recursive IIFE:

```
(function foo(count) {
    //...
    foo(count + 1);
})(0);
```

I know this is perfectly valid JS, but I vaguely remember hearing about some kind of bug in Internet Explorer where it didn't support named IIFEs correctly. Google hasn't turned up anything about it. Is there a browser-compatibility issue with using a named, recursive IIFE?

Answer (score 0):

This works in IE 11

```
(function foo(count) {
    if (count < 10)
      foo(count +1);
    else
      console.log(count);
}(0));
```